# CSS "input:focus + label" to change label style when LABEL is not adjacent to INPUT. Is it possible?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an INPUT followed by a LABEL in order to simulate a placeholder. When focus is on the control or there is a value in it, the label moves upwards.

So far, so good.... however, some INPUT's are attached to a jquery object (for instance, a datetime object). When focus is on the control, a DIV that contains the calendar just after the INPUT. That DIV is placed between the INPUT and the LABEL, so the CSS structure "input:focus + label" does not work anymore.

Is there a way to do the same, but for the next LABEL, even when that LABEL is not adjacent to the INPUT in DOM?

Regards
Jaime

Comment: Please add the respective code

Comment: what code? the question is just what to use instead of "input:focus + label" when label does not follow the INPUT. CSS classes inside the "input:focus + label" block are not taken into account when the LABEL does not follow... so there is no code to show you. Or maybe you mean about other code... please specify.

Comment: You kind of need to add atleast the dom structure to the question. It will be much helpful for the readers to understand the problem

Comment: There are ways, but we don't know what your HTML is. Create a snippet that shows the HTML that you want, then we can tell you if it's possible

Comment: Thanks, but I have already solved the problem with the answers. I thought it was clear that the final structure was <INPUT><DIV><LABEL>, since I wrote that the DIV (showing the calendar) was placed between the INPUT and the LABEL.... thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi , Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the sibling selector `~`.

```
input:focus ~ label
```

The sibling must come after the element not before.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 1):

Besides the sibling selector, as ngearing suggests, you can also use two adjacent selectors so you can be sure that you're selecting only the label that is two elements over from the input:

```
input:focus + div + label
```

Where `div` is whatever selector you use to select the calendar element.

Comment: Thanks too.... I will take this into account... I did not know "+" sign could be added to reach exactly the sibling I was looking for.